# logarithm and absolut value in returns of stocks

Tags: garch, log-returns

Well, i'm interested in model a GARCH for a serie. The original serie is $y_t$ (price index of a Stock Market), which has a unit root. So i create the returns:
$x_t = ln(y_t) - ln(y_{t-1})$.
Now, i'm confused about the fact of using $\lvert x_t\rvert$ for my GARCH. Why can i use absolute value, i'm thinking, that because i want to model volatility i'm just interested in how the series deviates from his mean in a period of time? Thank's a lot for the answers!

Comment: $\lvert x_t\rvert$ gives you the size of the change on day t without regard to sign, that is what volatility is: how big the changes are without considering whether they are positive or negative. Volatility can be estimated by averaging $\lvert x_t\rvert$ or $x^2$ over many days.

Comment: S. Cow, Can you detail your question ? it is not clear to me.

Comment: I agree this is not very clear. If you want to use a GARCH to capture heteroskedasticity you do not need to work with $\vert x_t \vert $ since in GARCH the conditional variance of $x_t$ is autoregressive by definition.

Comment: An answer is available for the same question posted at Cross Validated [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213395/logarithm-and-absolute-value-in-returns-of-stocks/213511#213511).

Comment: This question was already asked and answered [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/213395/6300).

Answer (score 0):

You can plot $\vert x_t \vert$ or $x^2$ just to see whether your data presents volatility clusters (periods in which volatility is high and other periods in which it is low). When you fit a GARCH model, you fit it simply on the $x_t$ series, not on the $\vert x_t \vert$ or $x^2$ series (as previously said in the comments): the likelihood algorithm will do the work.